# SWRLTab and JessTab in Protege 3.4.8

Tags: protege, jess, swrl

I am using Protege 3.4.8 and I want to execute some rules (using SWRL & Jess). I have create some rules for my ontology in protege but when I click the SWRLJess Tab button ([Screenshot - Protege 3.4.8 SWRL tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS6g1.png).), nothing happens.

Does anyone know if jess still works in Protege? Could anybody help me?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you see any exception while trying to activate the Jess tab?
Have it worked before for you?

We're having the same result, but with an exception creating the rule engine.

Comment: It is the first time I try to work with the Jess. 
Does not create exception. The only displayed in Jess tab is that the Jess will expire in 22 days. Nothing else.